# HTML/CSS float left automatically fill white space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have created a dash board that connects to sql to get status of a job. each collection of jobs is shown in a Div that is set to float left. if everything is good it looks like below:

[image]

when there is an error the div that contains the job automatically expands to show the job and it then looks like:

[image]

i was wondering if there is a way for the other divs to adjust and move into the white space? im guessing this wont be possible using just HTML and CSS so i am willing to use jquery if anyone knows of any add ins that can easily do this!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: please make a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). Masonry is a JavaScript grid layout library.

Answer (score 0):

I think `float:left` is creating his own block

you need to use `display property`

here is an example as you need:

```
ul {display:table;}
ul li {display:table-cell;}
```

and if you want to keep div property is `float:left;` so you need to give `position:absolute` to the error part(error main tag).

or after seeing the error you can use jquery hide event when user click close button then it will hide.

`JS Fiddle` Link: http://jsfiddle.net/abidkhanweb/mqz9j060/2/

Try this:

```js
$('.close').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide(); 
});
```

```css
.main{ width:100%;}
.sub{width:23%; position:relative; background:green; height:80px; float:left; margin:1%;}
.sub .error{position:absolute; width:100%; left:0px; top:0px; background:red; height:100px; z-index:10;}
.sub .error .close{position:absolute; right:10px; top:10px; text-align:center; font-size:11px; background:#FF0; height:20px; width:35px; cursor:pointer; content:"";}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub">
    <div class="error">
      <span class="close">close</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a  good way to use jsfiddle, with content in your answer as well.